# I have an array that I need to transform in a object (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Well, basically I have an array that has an objects with names and this objects has an array of objects inside, looks likes this:

```
var array = [
  {articles: [
    {number: "123"},
    {number: "143"},
  ]},
  {paragraph: [
    {number: "197"},
  ]},
]
```

And I'm really willing to get a object value in return, like this

```
{articles: [...], paragraph: [...]}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [an array reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const array = [
  { articles: [{ number: "123" }, { number: "143" }] },
  { paragraph: [{ number: "197" }] },
];

const formatted = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(currentValue);
    return { ...accumulator, [key]: value }
}, {});

console.log(formatted);
```

What we're doing is initializing our reducer with an empty object on line 9, and iterating over the array. Each time we iterate, we're returning the object with the new key and value appended to the end of it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem with no worries <3

Answer (score 1):

You could group by the outer properties of the nested objects.

```js
const
    array = [{ articles: [{ number: "123" }, { number: "143" }] }, { paragraph: [{ number: "197" }] }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, a]) => (r[k] ??= []).push(...a));

        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first answer, both are equivalence, and I only took the first one because as named, was the first, so I used, but thank you, I upvoted your solution too <3

Answer (score 1):

[Iterate over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the keys and values.

```js
const array=[{articles:[{number:"123"},{number:"143"}]},{paragraph:[{number:"197"}]}];

const out = {};

for (const obj of array) {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(obj);
  out[key] = value;
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first answer, using the reduce version, but your version was nice too, and very intuitive, thank you again <3

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
  {articles: [
    {number: "123"},
    {number: "143"},
  ]},
  {paragraph: [
    {number: "197"},
  ]},
]


let obj = {}
array.forEach(a => {

   if('articles' in a){
       obj.articles = a.articles
   }

   if('paragraph' in a){
       obj.paragraph = a.paragraph
   }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Worked, but, this solution requires to add a condition for every new type imputed, so, not that scalable, although I found this a good answer, if I've only two types, but thank you anyway around.